# Analog to digital module on IAR embedded workbench

Tags: workbench, iar

I have just started to work on this workbench for stellaris 6965.   My task is to convert a 5V analog input to digital and light up an LED.
Please tell me how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that needs to be done is to read the analog input and obtain the digital value (which will be memorized into one of the ADC registers).

The value you will receive will range between 0 - 1023 (2^8-1), if you use an 8-bit ADC. The exact register where your value will be memorized depends on the analog pin you have the input voltage.

After that, you can compare the value of the register (I recommend memorizing it into a variable first since it's volatile -> it can change at any moment) and set a threshold for lighting the LED. So, if your value is greater than x (where x is your threshold) you set the digital output pin to 1. Otherwise you set it to zero.

The operations described above can be put into the main program loop or in a timer interrupt.